# Rails postgreSQL GroupingError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

So I'm struggling with what seems to be a common problem. I developed my rails app with SQLite and have now pushed it to Heroku (postgreSQL) and encountered this error:

```
GroupingError: ERROR:  column "projects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

as a result of my code:

```
@projects = @user.projects.select('MAX(id), *').group(:unique_id).all.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

where I pull all of a `user`'s `project`s. `unique_id` identifies each project and I use `MAX(id)`as a way of pulling the most recent version of the project.

How can I change my code so that it works is both SQLite for development and postgreSQL for production? I've looked at several other questions that deal with this error but haven't found a great solution for what I'm doing. I'm inclined to use `distinct` instead of `group` but I'm not sure how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have `unique_id` as some sort of project identifier. Within each `unique_id`, each row represents a version of the project. You want to grab the most recent versions of each project?

Comment: @muistooshort exactly!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the "*" in the `select` method. If you replace that with "unique_id", you should satisfy the SQL parser.

```
@projects = @user.projects.select('MAX(id), unique_id').group(:unique_id).all.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Comment: Hmm, if I replace the `*`  with `unique_id`, I believe it only pulls the unique_id field for each project. I tried it and using this code throws a bunch more errors.

Comment: It *should* select the unique_id *and* the max(id), giving all you need to identify the most recent version of a project. It won't select other columns that you might need, but I think selecting other columns is the reason for the error.

Comment: So if I need the other columns for each project, would you suggest then running another query to get those based on the `id`s & `unique_id`s in `@projects`? If so, what would this look like?

Answer (score 0):

It would look like this. Select max(id), unique_id, other_column1, other_column2, etc... You then will have to group by the other columns.

Comment: If I group by the other columns, how would I have records that are distinct by the 'unique_id'?